# Getting the following BTDF Error - export settings file not being found

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020, btdf

I have BizTalk 2020 project, which builds no errors. I installed the visual studio 2019 [plugin](https://github.com/BTDF/ToolsForVisualStudio/files/6824382/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkToolsForVS2019.zip) for BizTalk 2020, I also installed BTDF v5.8 and setup a deployment project with the necessary exported settings. And I have tried to search for solution but as yet have found none.

I getting the following error

> “error MSB3073: The command “”C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployment Framework for BizTalk 5.8\Framework\DeployTools\xmlpreprocess.exe” /v /c /noDirectives /i:”C:\xxx\PortBindingsMaster.xml” /o:”C:\xxx\Deployment\PortBindings.xml” /d:CurDir=”C:\xxx” **/s:”””** exited with code 1. [C:\xxx\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj]
> Done Building Project “C:\xxx\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj” (Deploy target(s)) — FAILED.”

This project have recently been upgraded from BizTalk 2006 via BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing /s parameter is the $(SettingsFilePath) variable. Does your solution have build configurations named Debug and Release? The default names were changed at one point. I think originally they were called Development and Deployment (?). If not, use the solution's configuration editor dialog to rename them.

Tom